# change the xml to something like tree wise

Tags: xml, xslt

this is my xml o/p:-

```
<products>
    <region_timezone>1</region_timezone>
    <registrationstatus>2</registrationstatus>
    <eventstatus>2</eventstatus>
    <dist_activity>5,10068,10070</dist_activity>
    <dist_region>5069,5069,5069</dist_region>
    <dist_value>55,342,86</dist_value>
    <dist_unit>1,1,1</dist_unit>
    <dist_map>5</dist_map>
    <entryfee_currency>USD</entryfee_currency>
    <reg_str_dt>2013-01-14 20:35:00</reg_str_dt>
    <reg_end_dt>2013-01-14 20:35:00</reg_end_dt>
    <individual_label>19+++</individual_label>
    <individual_born_from>1980-08-21</individual_born_from>
    <individual_born_to>2010-08-18</individual_born_to>
    <individual_sex>3</individual_sex>
    <individual_strdt>2013-01-14 20:35:00</individual_strdt>
    <individual_start>2013-01-14 20:35:00</individual_start>
    <elite_sex>1</elite_sex>
    <tab_id>351</tab_id>
    <product_id>1</product_id>
    <tab_name>test1</tab_name>
    <region_timezone>1</region_timezone>
    <registrationstatus>2</registrationstatus>
    <eventstatus>2</eventstatus>
    <dist_activity>5,10069,10070</dist_activity>
    <dist_region>4457,7140,5069</dist_region>
    <dist_value>55,213,86</dist_value>
    <dist_unit>1,1,1</dist_unit>
    <dist_map>5</dist_map>
    <entryfee_currency>USD</entryfee_currency>
    <reg_str_dt>2013-02-14 20:39:00</reg_str_dt>
    <reg_end_dt>2013-02-14 20:39:00</reg_end_dt>
    <individual_label>19+++</individual_label>
    <individual_born_from>1980-08-21</individual_born_from>
    <individual_born_to>2010-08-18</individual_born_to>
    <individual_sex>3</individual_sex>
    <individual_strdt>2013-02-14 20:39:00</individual_strdt>
    <individual_start>2013-02-14 20:39:00</individual_start>
    <elite_sex>1</elite_sex>
    <tab_id>352</tab_id>
    <product_id>2</product_id>
    <tab_name>test2</tab_name>
</products>
```

here is my code(test.xsl):-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:template>

 <!-- from dimitre\'s xsl.thanks -->
 <xsl:template match="node[position()>1]/text()">
   <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is my php file:-

```
$sourcedoc = new DOMDocument();
$sourcedoc->load('test.xml');

$stylesheet = new DOMDocument();
$stylesheet->load('test.xsl');

// create a new XSLT processor and load the stylesheet
$xsltprocessor = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsltprocessor->importStylesheet($stylesheet);

// save the new xml file
file_put_contents('test-translated.xml', $xsltprocessor->transformToXML($sourcedoc));
```

i want to some changes in them like this:-

```
<product>
  <product_id value="1">
     <tab_id value="351">
         <tab_name value="test1"></tab_name> 
         <region_id>1</region_id>
         <region_time>27,02,2013</region_time>
     </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</product>
```

i want to this type of output...

IF ITS Possible using Xslt then good...

other wise any way to solve them help me 
thanks..
exactly i have multiple tag if i apply on them this code there is not generate perfect o/... as i need

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="product_id" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product_id">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../tab_id" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tab_id">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../tab_name" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../region_id | ../region_time" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, produces this output:

```
<product>
  <product_id value="1">
    <tab_id value="351">
      <tab_name value="test1" />
      <region_id>1</region_id>
      <region_time>27,02,2013</region_time>
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</product>
```

Is that the kind of thing you're going for, or are you looking for something more generic?  If you need something more generic, please explain how your scenario could be made more general?

Comment: thanks JLRishe  its good work but i have multiple tab so i apply this code on them so its not generate perfect o/p.. please check my edited in xml

Comment: Your sample XML now has no region_ids or region_times. Where should those come from?

Comment: its a just a sample xml and with our xsl file i am change the this line       <xsl:apply-templates select="../tab_name|../region_timezone | ../registrationstatus |../eventstatus |../dist_activity |../dist_region |../dist_value |../dist_unit |../dist_map |../entryfee_currency |../reg_str_dt |../reg_end_dt |../individual_label |../individual_born_from |../individual_born_to |../individual_sex |../individual_strdt |../individual_start |../elite_sex" />

Comment: I don't know what that means.  You need to clearly define your requirements before I can help you.  What would be the desired output from your current sample XML?

Comment: check this question:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195405/convert-xml-file-to-attribute-xml#comment21410917_15195405