# Convert XML file to attribute XML

Tags: php, xml, xslt

This is my simple XML file:-

```
<products>
    <value>
        <value>
            <region_timezone>
                <value>1</value>
            </region_timezone>
            <registrationstatus>
                <value>2</value>
            </registrationstatus>
            <eventstatus>
                <value>2</value>
            </eventstatus>
            <dist_activity>
                <value>5</value>
                <value>10068</value>
                <value>10070</value>
            </dist_activity>
            <reg_str_dt>
                <value>2013-01-14 20:35:00</value>
            </reg_str_dt>
            <reg_end_dt>
                <value>2013-01-14 20:35:00</value>
            </reg_end_dt>
            <product_id>1</product_id>
            <tab_id>351</tab_id>
            <tab_name>test1</tab_name>
        </value>
    </value>
    <value>
        <value>
            <region_timezone>
                <value>1</value>
            </region_timezone>
            <registrationstatus>
                <value>2</value>
            </registrationstatus>
            <eventstatus>
                <value>2</value>
            </eventstatus>
            <dist_activity>
                <value>5</value>
                <value>10069</value>
                <value>10070</value>
            </dist_activity>
            <reg_str_dt>
                <value>2013-02-14 20:39:00</value>
            </reg_str_dt>
            <reg_end_dt>
                <value>2013-02-14 20:39:00</value>
            </reg_end_dt>
            <product_id>2</product_id>
            <tab_id>352</tab_id>
            <tab_name>test2</tab_name>
        </value>
    </value>
</products>
```

I want to convert them to this:-

```
<products>
    <value>
        <value>
            <product_id value="1">
                <tab_id value="351">        
                    <tab_name value="test1"></tab_name>
                    <region_timezone value="1">
                    </region_timezone>
                    <registrationstatus value="2">
                    </registrationstatus>
                    <eventstatus value="2">
                    </eventstatus>
                    <dist_activity value="5,10068,10070">
                    </dist_activity>
                    <reg_str_dt value="2013-01-14 20:35:00">
                    </reg_str_dt>
                    <reg_end_dt value="2013-01-14 20:35:00">
                    </reg_end_dt>
                </tab_id>
            </product_id>
        </value>
    </value>
    <value>
        <value>
            <product_id value="2">
                <tab_id value="352">
                    <tab_name value="test2"></tab_name>
                    <region_timezone value="1">
                    </region_timezone>
                    <registrationstatus value="2">
                    </registrationstatus>
                    <eventstatus value="2">
                    </eventstatus>
                    <dist_activity value="5,10069,10070">
                    </dist_activity>
                    <reg_str_dt value="2013-02-14 20:39:00">
                    </reg_str_dt>
                    <reg_end_dt value="2013-02-14 20:39:00">
                    </reg_end_dt>
                </tab_id>
            </product_id>
        </value>
    </value>
</products>
```

Is It Possible Then Give Me Best Replay 
It's Possible With Php Code Then Best For Me...
I Have One Php File Thats Generate My Simple Xml File In The Sql Database...
Thanks

Comment: It is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: i have try some code in php i have try to display its in array but after display in array there dont display in xml as my o/p

Comment: in php i have use array_reverse()

Comment: in other way i am using xslt and php to convert xml file to my xml o/p...

Comment: hi in this answer i have one little bit problem if open this on notepad then each attribute value have &#10; with the value how to delete this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="value">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="products/value/value">
    <product_id value="{product_id}">
      <tab_id value="{tab_id}">
        <tab_name value="{tab_name}" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
      </tab_id>
    </product_id>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*[value[not(*)]]"
                           mode="values" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value[not(*)]" />

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="values">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="value[not(*)]" mode="values"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value" mode="values">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ',')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value[last()]" mode="values">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product_id | tab_id | tab_name" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<products>
  <product_id value="1">
    <tab_id value="351">
      <tab_name value="test1" />
      <region_timezone value="1" />
      <registrationstatus value="2" />
      <eventstatus value="2" />
      <dist_activity value="5,10068,10070" />
      <reg_str_dt value="2013-01-14 20:35:00" />
      <reg_end_dt value="2013-01-14 20:35:00" />
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
  <product_id value="2">
    <tab_id value="352">
      <tab_name value="test2" />
      <region_timezone value="1" />
      <registrationstatus value="2" />
      <eventstatus value="2" />
      <dist_activity value="5,10069,10070" />
      <reg_str_dt value="2013-02-14 20:39:00" />
      <reg_end_dt value="2013-02-14 20:39:00" />
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</products>
```

Comment: hey great job but a little bit problem <product_id><tab_id><tab_name> is display at buttom

Comment: Ok, fixed.  When you ask a question, you should describe, in words, what you want to accomplish. We shouldn't have to dig through your examples to figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks and sure in next time i will care of this i think you are a king of xslt... !!!

Comment: i want to remove <value> tag in the o/p i am try to this code of xslt for this      
 <xsl:template match="value">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

Comment: So in other words, you want the `product_id`s directly inside the `products` node?

Comment: product_id inside products node

Comment: its possible? change above my simple xml file `<dist_activity>
                <value>5</value>
                <value>10069</value>
                <value>10070</value>
            </dist_activity>` to `<dist_activity value="5" value="0069" value="10070"/>`

Comment: sorry its not possible bcoz of duplicate attribute but can possible this:`<dist_activity>
                <value>5</value>
                <value>10069</value>
                <value>10070</value>
            </dist_activity>` to `<dist_activity value="5"/> <dist_activity value="0069"/><dist_activity value="10070"/>`

Comment: @user2122438 Yes, this should be possible. Could you open that as a separate question and post a link to it here in the comments?

Comment: just now post a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472712/creat-xml-element-value-to-attribute-with-same-tag-name