# how to remove &#10; in xml with xsl transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

goto this link [Convert XML file to attribute XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195405/convert-xml-file-to-attribute-xml/15196154#15196154)
and copy/past my question xml file(with name "xml_simple.xml") 
and copy/past answer xslt then (with name "xslt4convert.xsl")
copy/past this php file  
php code:-

```
<?php
    $sourcedoc = new DOMDocument();
    $sourcedoc->load('xml_simple.xml');
    $stylesheet = new DOMDocument();
    $stylesheet->load('xslt4convert.xsl');

    // create a new XSLT processor and load the stylesheet
    $xsltprocessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    $xsltprocessor->importStylesheet($stylesheet);

    // save the new xml file
    file_put_contents('xml_converted.xml', $xsltprocessor->transformToXML($sourcedoc));

echo ' xml convert';
?>
```

and run this php file its generate new xml file 
open this file to notepad
`&#10;` in every attribute value

its display one space in browser how to delete this `&#10;`

 is display in notepad if i open xml file in to notepad
thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stylesheet should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!--
  Identity transform: copy all nodes that don't have overriding templates as is
  -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@value">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
      <!--
      Use the translate() function to replace all &#10; entities with an empty
      string
      -->
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#10;', '')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
  <product_id value="1">
    <tab_id value="351">
      <tab_name value="test1"/>
      <region_timezone value="1"/>
      <dist_region value="5069,5069,5069"/>
      <dist_value value="55,342,86"/>
      <reg_str_dt value="2013-01-14 20:35:00"/>
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
  <product_id value="2">
    <tab_id value="352">
      <tab_name value="test2"/>
      <region_timezone value="1"/>
      <dist_region value="4457,7140,5069"/>
      <dist_value value="55,213,86"/>
      <reg_end_dt value="2013-02-14 20:39:00"/>
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</products>
```

Comment: yes but its not return attribute value like<abc value="A2Z"/>its display <abc><value>A2Z</value></abc>

Comment: @user2122438: There was an element missing from my initial answer (sorry about that!), but I edited it immediately afterwards; please try copy-pasting the code from my answer again and try once more.

Comment: exactly my question is that i have open xml file in notepad then its op is above in my qustion if open in browser its look fine perfect no &#10;

Comment: check this my first question when i start this xml work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195405/convert-xml-file-to-attribute-xml

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're after. Can you add a sample of your expected output into your original question?

Comment: sure i am edit my original question but i request you first goto this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195405/convert-xml-file-to-attribute-xml/15196154#15196154 and copy/past my question xml file and then copy xlst file of answer and php file in the answer then run the php file its generate one xml file open this in to browser and notepad then you easly understand my question

Comment: sory php file not on them then just download xml of the given link  question and there answer xslt file and php code i have edit in this question please check

Comment: thanks for all support i got solve my problem its error in my basic php file thanks man thanks for listen me