# creat xml element value to attribute with same tag name

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my simple XML file:-

```
<products>
    <value>
        <value>
            <region_timezone>
                <value>1</value>
            </region_timezone>
            <registrationstatus>
                <value>2</value>
            </registrationstatus>
            <eventstatus>
                <value>2</value>
            </eventstatus>
            <dist_activity>
                <value>5</value>
                <value>10068</value>
                <value>10070</value>
            </dist_activity>
            <reg_str_dt>
                <value>2013-01-14 20:35:00</value>
            </reg_str_dt>
            <reg_end_dt>
                <value>2013-01-14 20:35:00</value>
            </reg_end_dt>
            <product_id>1</product_id>
            <tab_id>351</tab_id>
            <tab_name>test1</tab_name>
        </value>
    </value>
    <value>
        <value>
            <region_timezone>
                <value>1</value>
            </region_timezone>
            <registrationstatus>
                <value>2</value>
            </registrationstatus>
            <eventstatus>
                <value>2</value>
            </eventstatus>
            <dist_activity>
                <value>5</value>
                <value>10069</value>
                <value>10070</value>
            </dist_activity>
            <reg_str_dt>
                <value>2013-02-14 20:39:00</value>
            </reg_str_dt>
            <reg_end_dt>
                <value>2013-02-14 20:39:00</value>
            </reg_end_dt>
            <product_id>2</product_id>
            <tab_id>352</tab_id>
            <tab_name>test2</tab_name>
        </value>
    </value>
</products>
```

i try this xslt:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="value">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="products/value/value">
    <product_id value="{product_id}">
      <tab_id value="{tab_id}">
        <tab_name value="{tab_name}" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
      </tab_id>
    </product_id>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*[value[not(*)]]"
                           mode="values" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value[not(*)]" />

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="values">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="value[not(*)]" mode="values"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value" mode="values">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ',')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value[last()]" mode="values">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product_id | tab_id | tab_name" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with use of this xslt:- i done o/p something like this type:-

```
<products>
  <product_id value="1">
    <tab_id value="351">
      <tab_name value="test1" />
      <region_timezone value="1" />
      <registrationstatus value="2" />
      <eventstatus value="2" />
      <dist_activity value="5,10068,10070" />
      <reg_str_dt value="2013-01-14 20:35:00" />
      <reg_end_dt value="2013-01-14 20:35:00" />
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
  <product_id value="2">
    <tab_id value="352">
      <tab_name value="test2" />
      <region_timezone value="1" />
      <registrationstatus value="2" />
      <eventstatus value="2" />
      <dist_activity value="5,10069,10070" />
      <reg_str_dt value="2013-02-14 20:39:00" />
      <reg_end_dt value="2013-02-14 20:39:00" />
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</products>
```

but i need this type of o/p:-

```
<products>
  <product_id value="1">
    <tab_id value="351">
      <tab_name value="test1" />
      <region_timezone value="1" />
      <registrationstatus value="2" />
      <eventstatus value="2" />
      <dist_activity value="5" />
      <dist_activity value="10068" />
      <dist_activity value="10070" />
      <reg_str_dt value="2013-01-14 20:35:00" />
      <reg_end_dt value="2013-01-14 20:35:00" />
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
  <product_id value="2">
    <tab_id value="352">
      <tab_name value="test2" />
      <region_timezone value="1" />
      <registrationstatus value="2" />
      <eventstatus value="2" />
      <dist_activity value="5" />
      <dist_activity value="10069" />
      <dist_activity value="10070" />
      <reg_str_dt value="2013-02-14 20:39:00" />
      <reg_end_dt value="2013-02-14 20:39:00" />
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</products>
```

here i dont need to comma-separate(,) in my current  o/p. i want to separate  this element attiribute value as above xml output like:-

```
          <dist_activity value="5" />
          <dist_activity value="10069" />
          <dist_activity value="10070" />
```

please help me out of this...
if its possible...
thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/value">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="products/value/value">
    <product_id value="{product_id}">
      <tab_id value="{tab_id}">
        <tab_name value="{tab_name}" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
      </tab_id>
    </product_id>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[value[not(*)]]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="value[not(*)]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value[not(*)]">
    <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
      <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../@* | ../node()[not(self::value[not(*)])]" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product_id | tab_id | tab_name" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<products>
  <product_id value="1">
    <tab_id value="351">
      <tab_name value="test1" />
      <region_timezone value="1" />
      <registrationstatus value="2" />
      <eventstatus value="2" />
      <dist_activity value="5" />
      <dist_activity value="10068" />
      <dist_activity value="10070" />
      <reg_str_dt value="2013-01-14 20:35:00" />
      <reg_end_dt value="2013-01-14 20:35:00" />
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
  <product_id value="2">
    <tab_id value="352">
      <tab_name value="test2" />
      <region_timezone value="1" />
      <registrationstatus value="2" />
      <eventstatus value="2" />
      <dist_activity value="5" />
      <dist_activity value="10069" />
      <dist_activity value="10070" />
      <reg_str_dt value="2013-02-14 20:39:00" />
      <reg_end_dt value="2013-02-14 20:39:00" />
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</products>
```